# Div on the left needs to overflow when it collides with div on the right

Tags: html, css

I've made 3 examples of what I'd like to achieve.
I have 2 divs side by side in a wrapper that has 100% as width, the left div has a width of 100% minus the width of the righter div, the righter div has an auto width.

When the left div text isn't long enough to hit the righter div, the left div should extend till the righter div.
[image]

When the content in the left div is too long, it should overflow to a new line, the righter div will keep it's width.
[image: First image]

When the content increases in righter div, the left div should adjust its width and overflow if needed.
[image]

Is there a way to do this without javascript and preferably without flex?

Comment: put your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex` for that:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.left {
  background: gray;
  flex: 1;
}

.right {
  background: green;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flex is supported by IE11, even by IE10 using the ``-ms-`` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign `display: flex;` to the wrapper DIV - that should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Flexbox` to do this, you just need to set `flex: 1` on left div so it takes free width. Also to remove white-space when text wraps you can use `word-break: break-all` so it breaks on each letter and to make items keep its own height you can add `align-items: flex-start` [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1243/)

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.left {
  background: lightblue;
  word-break: break-all;
  flex: 1;
}
.right {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div>
  <div class="right">loremipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this is what your are looking for.

```css
.leftdiv {background: green;flex: 1;}

.container {display: flex;align-items: flex-start;}

.rightdiv {background: red;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftdiv">
    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="rightdiv">
    hello world
  </div>
</div>
</br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftdiv">
    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem      ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="rightdiv">
    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem 
  </div>
</div>
```